# I got single line as output, but i have to get given number of rows

Tags: python-3.x

code:

```
row = int(input('enter a number:'))

while row != 0:
    for i in range(row, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            print(i, end=" ")
        row = row - 1
```

actual output:

```
enter a number:4
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

expected output:

```
enter a number:4
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

Comment: you are decresing `row` inside the for loop, instead you should do it in the the while loop, additionally to for loop that run for a limited number of times is better to use a for-loop over a range like `for _ in range(number_of_times)` (the `_` part is just convention for a throw away variable) so there is no need to worry about indices or counters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `tmp` and `for-loop` at first, ***(I don't change or improve your code)***

Try this:

```
row = int(input('enter a number:'))
tmp = row
for _ in range(tmp):
    row = tmp
    while row != 0:
        for i in range(row, 0, -1):
            for j in range(i):
                print(i, end=" ")
            row = row - 1
    print()
```

Output:

```
enter a number:5
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1 
5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

For improving you can try this:

```
row = int(input('enter a number:'))
for _ in range(row):
    print(*[f'{i} '*i for i in range(row,0,-1)], sep="")
```